# Capture entire string only if last part meets criteria

Tags: regex

I have the following URLs.

```
example.com/ie/ie/womens-c-1.html
example.com/ie/womens-c-1.html
```

I would only like the regex to capture the string if `/ie/` is specified once.

I have a pattern that captures up to the first `/ie/`

```
([a-z.-]*)\/([a-z]{2})\/
```

I can't work out the last part, to ensure the string is only captured if the pattern matches

`/ie/(*.)-c-([0-9]*).html`

Do I need to use lookahead or something similar?

Update: Anything after the first `/ie/` wont contain a `/` can I use this to help build the rule?

I would like the final capture groups to be as followed. (Groups denoted by parentheses) `(example.com)/(ie)/(womens)-c-(1).html`

Comment: Do you want to match urls where `ie` appears more than once?

Comment: No I would like them to be ignored. This is for a htaccess file. So I do not wish the match to resolve if more than one /ie/

Comment: Your post is a bit not clear. Can you add some strings that should match and some strings that should not match, stating the logic for match?

Comment: For a rewrite rule use `^(?!.*(/ie/).*\1).*/ie/`. No more regex.

Comment: Extending your current regex, to not allow a `/` later in the string, you can `^([a-z.-]*)\/([a-z]{2})\/[^\/]*$` regex. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Chsm3d/1) Let me know if this works.

Comment: @revo please could you explain how I would get the desired capture groups in this?

Comment: Note that `()` are parentheses. Brackets are `[]`.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thanks, that works to exclude the line I dont want. But doesn't include the last two capture groups.

Comment: @sean thanks. How could I modify your answer to ensure the capture groups are as desired?

Comment: @atoms: Updated my regex to capture the two info in two groups the way you want. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/Chsm3d/2/) Let me know if this works.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi that works perfectly!

Comment: Are you using this within htaccess rules? where do you want to utilize and work with capturing groups?

Comment: @revo I am. Its part a very old system. We use the capture groups to load the correct content.

Comment: Please show the rules and the way you are back-referencing to capturing groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in your post, extending your regex to only match URLs, that has two alpha characters followed by a `/` and what follows next doesn't contain any further `/` characters and remaining information gets further collected in two more groups,

```
^([a-z.-]*)\/([a-z]{2})\/([^\/]*)-c-(\d*)\.html
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Chsm3d/2/)**